# Import all the namesepace of the package in R in another package

Tags: r, package

I need to fix a certain function in a certain package (Function `layer_model_predictions` in package **ggvis**). I am lazy, so I do not want to prepend `ggvis:::` to all the calls to *ggvis* specific functions.

So I figured I create a small R package to solve this problem, import all the functions from ggvis and be happy. However Roxygen's `@import ggvis` imports only those functions which are exported by *ggvis*. Is at all possible to get unfettered access to all functions declared in *ggvis* code? Or for that matter any R package?

One solution is simply to fork the package and get the fix in the package code directly but I suppose there are reasons for not doing that.